# ошибка postgresql при старте сервиса

Tags: postgresql

root@localhost:~# service postgresql start
[....] Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server: main[....] 
Error: /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl /usr/lib/postgresql/11/bin/pg_ctl start -D /var/lib/postgresql/11/main -l /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log -s -o -c config_file="/etc/postgresql/11/main/postgresql.conf" exited with status 1:

2019-04-08 20:01:29.069 EEST [28485] СООБЩЕНИЕ: не удалось создать сокет IPv6 для адреса "::1": Отказано в доступе

2019-04-08 20:01:29.075 EEST [28485] СООБЩЕНИЕ: не удалось создать сокет IPv4 для адреса "127.0.0.1": Отказано в доступе

2019-04-08 20:01:29.076 EEST [28485] ПРЕДУПРЕЖДЕНИЕ: не удалось создать принимающий сокет для "localhost"

2019-04-08 20:01:29.077 EEST [28485] ВАЖНО: не удалось создать сокеты TCP/IP

2019-04-08 20:01:29.077 EEST [28485] СООБЩЕНИЕ: с[FAILа БД выключена pg_ctl: не удалось запустить сервер Изучите протокол выполнения. ... failed!

Comment: Покажите содержимое параметра **listen_addresses** в файле postgresql.conf

Comment: и `port` оттуда же